# postgresql: parameterize aggregation type?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql

I need to provide a number of stored procedures that return the result of an aggregate function run on a selection of values in the database, i.e. average, sum, min, max, etc. The selection of values is always done in a similar manner.

My first, naive implementation consists of one stored proc per aggregate function type, e.g. get_avg(...), get_sum(...). The functions obviously share quite a lot of duplicate code. I wonder if there is a way to move the aggregate type into a parameter or so and then use one stored proc only, e.g. get_aggregate(aggr_type, ...)

The only way I can think of as far as the pl/pgsql implementation is concerned is to select the values that should go into the aggregate and then use that in as many if aggr_type == ... / else clauses as there are aggregate types. This is not very flexible though and requires change of the code whenever a new aggregate type should be supported.

Is there any way to parameterize the name of a function in pl/pgsql ?
Can ayone think of an approach that I fail to see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, technically, use the `execute` statement in your plpgsql function:

```
return query
execute $x$
select id, $x$ || quote_ident(agg_func) || $x$(col)::numeric as agg
from bar
$x$;
```

(See below for a proper example). The issue is, this will mean parsing/planning your query on every call.

On occasion, a better option will be to create a function that creates the various needed functions. Something like this:

```
create or replace function generate_agg_functions(_table regclass) returns void as $$
declare
  _agg_type text[] = '{sum, avg}';
  _ret_type regtype[] = '{numeric, numeric}';
  rec record;
begin
  for rec in select _agg_type[i] as agg_type, _ret_type[i] as ret_type
  from generate_subscripts(_agg_type, 1) i
  loop
  execute $x$
  create or replace function $x$ || quote_ident(_table || '_' || rec.agg_func) || $x$()
    returns table (id int, $x$ || quote_ident(rec.agg_type) || ' ' || ret_type || $x$)
  $def$
  begin
    return query
    select id,
           $x$ || quote_ident(rec.agg_type) || $x$(col)::$x$ || rec.ret_type || $x$
             as $x$ || quote_ident(rec.agg_type) || $x$
    from $x$ || _table || $x$;
  end;
  $def$ language plpgsql stable;
  $x$;
  end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

It's a bit trickier to write, but you'll end up not duplicating code without compromising the performance of the individual aggregates.

Comment: wow! i feel right now like i still have a lot to learn about postgresql. maybe for the moment if aggr_type == ... / else is not such a bad option anymore. thanks for your help mate! :-)